# Perl v5.32 Installation in CentOS

Tags: linux, perl, centos

I have Centos 8(64 bit) installed in my Oracle VM VirtualBox.

When I heard announcement about Perl 7 release in Conference in the Cloud! A Perl and Raku Conf, eager to install it in my CentOS.

I tried to install (as a `root`) `Perl v5.32` as per the commands mentioned in [CPAN](https://www.cpan.org/src/) official website.

```
wget https://www.cpan.org/src/5.0/perl-5.32.0.tar.gz
tar -xzf perl-5.32.0.tar.gz
cd perl-5.32.0
./Configure -des -Dprefix=$HOME/localperl
make
make test
make install
```

Earlier I had `Perl v5.26` installed in my system.

```
[vinod@localhost ~]$ perl -v

This is perl 5, version 26, subversion 3 (v5.26.3) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi
(with 51 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)

Copyright 1987-2018, Larry Wall

Perl may be copied only under the terms of either the Artistic License or the
GNU General Public License, which may be found in the Perl 5 source kit.

Complete documentation for Perl, including FAQ lists, should be found on
this system using "man perl" or "perldoc perl".  If you have access to the
Internet, point your browser at http://www.perl.org/, the Perl Home Page.
```

Even after following the above steps to upgrade the Perl version, I didn't succeded.

It still shows me `Perl v5.26` when I check for the version after running commands mentioned above.

I want to know, whether I am doing something wrong or It is not a proper way to run a command to get upgraded version of Perl.

Comment: What does `perl -V` show? Note that you installed 5.32 in `$HOME/localperl`

Comment: perl -V shows: `[vinod@localhost ~]$ perl -V
Summary of my perl5 (revision 5 version 26 subversion 3) configuration:.......` And yeah I could see `lib`,`bin`,`man` inside `/home/vinod/localperl`.

Comment: Try run `$HOME/localperl/bin/perl --version`

Comment: Oh!! yeah now I can see `This is perl 5, version 32, subversion 0 (v5.32.0) built for x86_64-linux`. So how can I make use of it in my scripts?

Comment: A really nice way to have multiple Perls is [perlbrew](https://perlbrew.pl/)

Comment: @vkk05 Great. I agree with zdim, I think it would be easier to use it if you installed it with `perlbrew` since you most likely would need to reinstall the XS modules you used with 5.26.  They are not compatible with a new perl version. This is much simplified if you use perlbrew

Comment: @HåkonHægland Sure. As suggested by zdim, let me try install it with `perlbrew` and will let you know over here.

Comment: @HåkonHægland & zdim, Succeeded. thank you.

Comment: Just to be clear, Perl 7 doesn't have a release yet, and it's not v5.32. It's going to have the same syntax as v5.32, but that's a different statement.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, 5.32 and 7.0 are two different versions of Perl. The latter will be based on the former, but it will be different, and it hasn't been released yet.

---

You did not change your `PATH`, so `/usr/bin/perl` is still the `perl` found when you use `perl`.

You can provide the path to the `perl` you installed (`$HOME/localperl/bin/perl`), or you can adjust your `PATH` so that `$HOME/localperl/bin` is found before `/usr/bin`.

I install my additional copies of Perl using `perlbrew`. It helps you install Perl, and it makes it easy to change which one is used when you simply type `perl`.

```
$ perlbrew use 5.30t

$ perl -v | grep 'This is'
This is perl 5, version 30, subversion 2 (v5.30.2) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi

$ perlbrew use 5.28t

$ perl -v | grep 'This is'
This is perl 5, version 28, subversion 2 (v5.28.2) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi
```

---

My setup:

```
$ \ls -Fl "${PERLBREW_ROOT:-$HOME/perl5/perlbrew}"/perls  # Output rearranged.
total 0
drwx------ 1 ikegami ikegami 4096 Mar 15 20:32 system/

drwxr-xr-x 1 ikegami ikegami 4096 May 22 14:12 5.10.1t/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ikegami ikegami    7 May 23 13:41 5.10t -> 5.10.1t/
drwxr-xr-x 1 ikegami ikegami 4096 May 22 14:51 5.12.5t/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ikegami ikegami    7 May 23 13:42 5.12t -> 5.12.5t/
drwxr-xr-x 1 ikegami ikegami 4096 May 22 16:39 5.14.4t/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ikegami ikegami    7 May 23 13:42 5.14t -> 5.14.4t/
drwxr-xr-x 1 ikegami ikegami 4096 May 23 12:58 5.16.3t/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ikegami ikegami    7 May 23 13:42 5.16t -> 5.16.3t/
drwxr-xr-x 1 ikegami ikegami 4096 May 23 16:45 5.18.4t/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ikegami ikegami    7 May 23 13:42 5.18t -> 5.18.4t/
drwxr-xr-x 1 ikegami ikegami 4096 May 24 13:44 5.20.3t/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ikegami ikegami    7 May 23 13:42 5.20t -> 5.20.3t/
drwxr-xr-x 1 ikegami ikegami 4096 May 24 16:41 5.22.4t/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ikegami ikegami    7 May 23 13:42 5.22t -> 5.22.4t/
drwxr-xr-x 1 ikegami ikegami 4096 May 24 21:41 5.24.4t/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ikegami ikegami    7 May 23 13:43 5.24t -> 5.24.4t/
drwxr-xr-x 1 ikegami ikegami 4096 May 25 11:11 5.26.3t/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ikegami ikegami    7 May 23 13:43 5.26t -> 5.26.3t/
drwxr-xr-x 1 ikegami ikegami 4096 May 26 11:20 5.28.2t/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ikegami ikegami    7 May 23 13:43 5.28t -> 5.28.2t/
drwxr-xr-x 1 ikegami ikegami 4096 May 23 13:44 5.30.2t/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ikegami ikegami    7 Mar 15 17:26 5.30t -> 5.30.2t/

lrwxrwxrwx 1 ikegami ikegami    7 Mar 15 17:26 latest -> 5.30.2t/

lrwxrwxrwx 1 ikegami ikegami    7 Apr 19 22:56 acpcw -> 5.30.2t/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ikegami ikegami    7 Apr  2 18:32 gloomhaven -> 5.30.2t/
...
```

- "t" stands for "threaded".
- I create symlinks for each project and use this symlink in the shebang line. That way, I can easily switch which `perl` a project uses (by changing the symlink). `perlbrew alias` can be used to create these symlinks.
- I create symlinks for 5.##t that point to the latest build of that version so I can do `perlbrew use 5.20t` (for example) to get the latest maintenance release of that build. `perlbrew alias` can be used to create these symlinks.
- I create a symlink named `system` so I can use `perlbrew use system` to use the system Perl. `perlbrew off` and `perlbrew switch-off` can be used instead of this now, but I still prefer the symlink.

I use the following tool to install new builds of Perl:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Basename qw( basename );
use Getopt::Long   qw( );


# -----


sub help {
   my $script_file = basename( $0 );

   print( <<"__EOI__" );
Creates a perlbrew install of the specified version of Perl.
Optionally, it will also install modules from CPAN afterwards.

Usage:
   $script_file --help
   $script_file [OPTIONS] [--] BUILD [MODULES]

Builds:
   5.x.y
   5.x.yd    Build with debug symbols (-g).
   5.x.yt    Build with thread support.
   5.x.ydt   Build with debug symbols (-g) and thread support.

options:
   -n        Skip tests.
   -j N      Run build and tests in parallel.
   --jobs=N  Run build and tests in parallel.
__EOI__

   exit( 0 );
}


sub usage_error {
   my $script_file = basename( $0 );
   print( STDERR $_[0] ) if @_;
   print( STDERR "Use $script_file --help to display usage\n" );
   exit( 1 );
}


sub parse_args {
   my $getopt = Getopt::Long::Parser->new(
      config => [qw(
         posix_default
      )],
   );

   my %opts = (
      threaded => undef,
      debug    => undef,
      taint    => 1,
      jobs     => undef,
      no_tests => 0,
   );

   $getopt->getoptions(
      'help|h|?' => \&help,
      'jobs|j=i' => \$opts{ jobs },
      'n!'       => \$opts{ no_tests },
   )
      or usage_error();

   @ARGV >= 1
      or usage_error( "Insufficient arguments\n" );

   my $build = shift( @ARGV );
   my $version = $build;
   $opts{ threaded } = $version =~ s/t\z//;
   $opts{ debug    } = $version =~ s/d\z//;

   $version =~ /^5\.[1-9][0-9]*\.(?:0|[1-9][0-9]*)\z/
      or usage_error( "Invalid version format\n" );

   return ( $build, $version, \%opts, @ARGV );
}


# -----


sub systemx {
   my ( $cmd, @args ) = @_;
   system { $cmd } $cmd, @args;
   die( "Can't run \"$cmd\": $!\n" )                    if $? == -1;
   die( "\"$cmd\" killed by signal ".($? & 0x7F)."\n" ) if $? & 0x7F;
   die( "\"$cmd\" exited with error ".($? >> 8)."\n" )  if $? >> 8;
}


sub perlbrew_install {
   my ( $build, $version, $opts ) = @_;

   my $perlbrew_root = $ENV{ PERLBREW_ROOT } || "$ENV{ HOME }/perl5/perlbrew";

   unlink( "$perlbrew_root/build.log" );

   my @cc_args;
   push @cc_args, "-DNO_TAINT_SUPPORT" if !$opts->{ taint };    # Causes *many* tests to fail.
   push @cc_args, "-DPERL_SUB_DEPTH_WARN=1000";                 # Causes some tests to fail.
   push @cc_args, "-DPERL_USE_UNSHARED_KEYS_IN_LARGE_HASHES";

   my @args;
   push @args, "-v";
   push @args, "-j", $opts->{ jobs }  if  $opts->{ jobs     };
   push @args, "-n"                   if  $opts->{ no_tests };
   push @args, $version;
   push @args, "--as=$build";
   push @args, "-Doptimize=-g"        if  $opts->{ debug    };
   push @args, "-Dusethreads"         if  $opts->{ threaded };
   push @args, "-Accflags='@cc_args'" if @cc_args;

   systemx( "perlbrew", "install", @args );
}


sub module_install {
   my ( $build, @modules ) = @_;
   return if !@modules;
   systemx( 'sh', '-c', 'perlbrew use "${@:1:1}" && cpan -- "${@:2}"', 'dummy', $build, @modules );
}


sub main {
   my ( $build, $version, $opts, @modules ) = @_;
   perlbrew_install( $build, $version, $opts );
   module_install( $build, @modules );
}


main( parse_args() );
```

Comment: thanks. I agree that I haven't gave proper path while installing it.

Comment: I didn't say anything of the kind.

Comment: ...though, now that you mention it, using a naming scheme allowing for the installation of more than one local perl would be nice.

Comment: Added my setup to my answer.